# Why is the login attempt returning {NotAllowed} in the PasswordSignInAsync method (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I used an identity in my ASP.NET project, it created the login and register feature automatically and i can register to the website just fine, after registering the account gets logged in and i can use all the features i made, but if i log out and try to log into the same account again the login process always fails.
The accounts are being stored in the database as following
[https://i.imgur.com/M1EbfGj.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrfoZ.png)

I didn't change the code that was made by visual studio 2019 and after debugging all i know is that the password is passed correctly to the database but the result comes out as {NotAllowed}, the line where that happens is

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

if someone wants to see the entire project it can be found in https://github.com/Alysty/TaskManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File that is most likely your issue: TaskManager/TaskManager/Areas/Identity/IdentityHostingStartup.cs

Location is in requiring the account to be confirmed in this line:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<TaskManagerUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
```

My guess is that your account is not confirmed so you need to confirm it or remove this constraint.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using TaskManager.Areas.Identity.Data;
using TaskManager.Data;

[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(TaskManager.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace TaskManager.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<TaskManagerUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using initial values because of I didn't need any detailed login process. But EmailConfirmed had been 'false' on DB. When ı was set it to 'true', my problem is solved.